# Difference between Hyperledger setups

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have a question about the difference between setting up Hyperledger v1 using getting start method :

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

and the other methods like using vagrant and make peer,
and which method is good and fits for both configuring roles and privacy also for configuring chaincodes.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getting started has it all contained within. You can bring up an entire Hyperledger Fabric V1.0 network on your local box (or in a hosted cloud environment if you'd like). You can also see how to break it down, to simply bring up a peer, or ordering service, etc, if you don't want the entire fabric.

Vagrant is good for development when you don't want to alter anything on your local box, easy to tear down, and start from scratch. The getting started has it all contained within. You can bring up an entire Hyperledger Fabric V1.0 network on your local box (or in a hosted cloud environment if you'd like). You can also see how to break it down, to simply bring up a peer, or ordering service, etc, if you don't want the entire fabric.

Vagrant is good for development when you don't want to alter anything on your local box, easy to tear down, and start from scratch.

Most would suggest to just use the getting started straight away which uses Docker containers. The only exception might be is if you are running on windows, in which case you might want to use vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 independent Hyperledger blockchain technologies. The setup for each one is different.

- Hyperledger Fabric--explained above
- Hyperledger Sawtooth--explained below
- Hyperledger Indy (Identity Managment focus)
- Hyperledger Iroha (Mobile app focus)
- Hyperledger Burrow (Ethereum EVM implementation)

The last three I will let others explain how to install and setup (since I do not know).

For Hyperledger Sawtooth, here are the instructions for the 1.x release of Sawtooth: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/installing_sawtooth.html

Here's a brief summary of the package installation steps and initial setup:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe'
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y sawtooth
$ sawtooth keygen
$ sawset genesis
$ sudo -u sawtooth sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch
$ sudo sawadm keygen
```